# ABAQUS python issue extracting deformed coordinates using COORD

Tags: python, abaqus, finite-element-analysis, abaqus-odb

I have produced a script for ABAQUS CAE using Python to extract the deformed coordinates of a node set called 'SET-1'. A load is applied to the top surface of the cube and the cube deforms.

The field output 'COORD' is supposed to give the deformed coordinates of nodes, I believe. But the coordinates I obtain are the original UNDEFORMED coordinates. I have requested them from the final step (after deformation). Does anyone have any suggestions as to what my issue could be?

NOTE: I have included nodal displacement in my code also, this was to check that I was requesting data from the correct step. If I was requesting data from the undeformed step, then my displacements would be zero. The displacements are ok, the COORD values are not.

My code is below:

```
from odbAccess import *

odb = openOdb(path='D:/AbaqusWorking/WIP/Job-1.odb')
modelname = "Cube coords"

# Create a variable that refers to the
# last frame of the first step.

lastFrame = odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[-1]

# Create a variable that refers to the deformed coordinates 'COORD' and 'U'
# in the last frame of the first step.

deformedCoord = lastFrame.fieldOutputs['COORD']
disp = lastFrame.fieldOutputs['U']

# Create a variable that refers to the node set 'SET-1'
# The set is  associated with the part instance 'PART-1-1'.

nSet = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].\
    nodeSets['SET-1']

# Create a variable that refers to the COORD and DISP of the node
# set in the last frame of the first step.

nodeCoords = deformedCoord.getSubset(region=nSet)
nodeDisp = disp.getSubset(region=nSet)

# Finally, print some field output data from each node
# in the node set (a single node in this example).

print '**********************'

def writeCoords():
    f = open("D:\AbaqusWorking\WIP\Coords1.csv", "w") 
    f.write("Model name,Node,X1,Y1,Z1" + "\n") 

    for v in nodeCoords.values:
        f = open("D:\AbaqusWorking\WIP\Coords1.csv", "a") 
        f.write(str(modelname) + "," )
        f.write(str(v.nodeLabel) + "," ) 
        f.write(str(v.data[0]) + "," + str(v.data[1]) + "," + str(v.data[2]) +"\n")
    f.close()
        
def writeDisp():
    f = open("D:\AbaqusWorking\WIP\Disp1.csv", "w") 
    f.write("Model name,Node,UX,UY,UZ" + "\n") 

    for v in nodeDisp.values:
        f = open("D:\AbaqusWorking\WIP\Disp1.csv", "a") 
        f.write(str(modelname) + "," )
        f.write(str(v.nodeLabel) + "," ) 
        f.write(str(v.data[0]) + "," + str(v.data[1]) + "," + str(v.data[2]) +"\n")
    f.close()    
     
        
writeCoords()
writeDisp()
   
print 'Write to file complete...'
print'...'
odb.close()
print 'ODB closed...'
print'...'
print '**********************'
```

Comment: Yeah, `'COORD'` outputs are always the undeformed condition.  To get what you want, you need `DeformedCoord + disp`.  This is done so you don't get truncation errors when the displacement is small compared to the coordinate system, which is important if you're trying to find even smaller rotations.